# I want to select all distinct for every column from sql table

Tags: sql

```
country     state   city    
Country1    state1  city5   
Country2    state2  city6   
Country5    state1  city6   
Country5    state3  city6   
Country2    state3  city9
```

i want to get distinct values from country, state, city and all these columns should not be blank. i tried couple of queries but does not work ..The output should be all distinct values as shown below

```
Country1    
Country2    
Country5    
state1
state2
state3
city5
city6
city9
```

Comment: Why is `Country1` listed 2x in the output if you want Distinct or is this a mistake in your output?

Comment: Yes... its a typo

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way is using `UNION`

```
Select country from yourtable
Union
Select state from yourtable
Union 
Select city from yourtable
```

This can be done at ease if your `DBMS` supports `APPLY` operator

```
SELECT datas
FROM   Youtable s
       CROSS apply (SELECT [country] UNION
                    SELECT [state] UNION
                    SELECT [city]) cs (datas)
```

If your `DBMS` supports `LATERAL` then (thanks to a_horse_with_no_name)

```
select t.x
from the_table
  cross join lateral (select country union select state union select city ) as t(x)
order by t.x
```

Comment: @Igor - `UNION` itself will removes duplicates

Comment: The equivalent in the SQL standard for `APPLY` is `LATERAL`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Ohh thank you will look it up.. I love this feature very handy

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - No it will.. I have unpivoted the data it using `UNION`

Comment: Ah, right. This would be the equivalent in standard SQL btw: http://rextester.com/ZZV88770

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Wow.. thanks for the demo.. Will keep it in mind.. This is why I love SO

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Added it in my answer hope you dont mind ;)

Comment: I would still prefer the `value()` clause of the cumbersome `select .. union` though ;)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - It just suits the requirement here. Initially even I wrote answer with `Values` constructor